# Using @Transactional correctly in Spring boot for big queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a method who calls 3 childs-methods before making a transaction with the repository, like this :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class ObjectService {

  @Transactional
  public void doSomething() {
    objectRepository.findAllObject();
    childMethod1();
    childMethod2();
    childMethod3();
    objectRepository.save(int id);
  }

  public void childMethod1() { 
    //do something
  } 

  public void childMethod2() { 
    //do something
  } 

  public void childMethod3() { 
    //do something
  } 

}
```

and the repository has a select and a save method :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM object WHERE id is null")
Optional<Obeject> findAllObject();

@Query("SELECT * FROM object WHERE id is null")
Optional<Obeject> save(int id);
```

In my case, if I'm using this system on a table with 100k entries, the application start with a quicl execution of the queries, but no transaction is realized (no move in the database), because the program seems to wait to do all the job before execute the repository method.

So, in fact, if I use this method on all the table entries, Spring boot become smaller and smaller and finish to be blocked without making one single change in the database.

So, actually, I've created an endpoint to do this with a loop of 1000entries. Just have to ping it with a bash job and it works but it's a dirty method.

I would like to know what is the best practice and if this second way is a good method for you :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class ObjectService {

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void doSomething() {
    objectRepository.findAllObject();
    childMethod1();
    childMethod2();
    childMethod3();
    objectRepository.save(int id);
  }

  public void childMethod1() { 
    //do something
  } 

  public void childMethod2() { 
    //do something
  } 

  public void childMethod3() { 
    //do something
  } 

}
```

If I understand correctly, the annotation

> @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

will do 1 transaction at the end of execution of the parent method for all objects return by the repository instead of waiting the end of the execution for all of the object, right?

Sorry if these questions seems simple for you, I'm trying to understand the documentation but it's difficult to understand with a bad level of english.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: add repository methods

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: It was more a complemenbtary question but, ok, I've deleted it. :)

Comment: "*... will do 1 transaction at the end of execution*" - No. The transaction is opened at the start of the `@Transactional` method (through an interceptor) and closed when the method returns. The **commit** happens when the method returns (again, through the interceptor).

Comment: Hum, this is strange because the repository wait the end of the execution of X-times execution of the method before writing in the database... Is it possible that @Transactional makes the commit and wait the end of the whole process to record them in the database with the repository?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. What I can tell you is that the commit must be a blocking call. It will bock until all data for the transaction has been commited to the database, or the commit has failed and the transaction has been rolled back.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more specific, sorry. The method will be used for 100k entries from the database. So, if I use only the @Transactional, the method is executed quickly to begin but after 10 mins, she become slower and slower. After 8hours, the method is executed very very slowly and I've to stop the application. Result: 0 change in the database...

Comment: ... do you call this method once per database row? If so: do you execute those calls in parallel? How did you determine that the first calls "finished"? I have a suspicion that there are unclosed transactions.

Comment: No, just a classic select ( select * from TABLE table where id is not null ) and using a repository save() methid at the end of the parent method (I've edited my post)

Comment: How did you determine that the first calls "finished"? Have you checked for idle transactions in the dbms? Have you checked that the machine, the program is running on, works fine and - especially - is not swapping?

Comment: I've check the api logs yes, and I see all logs (very quick to begin and very slower a moment later). The method works quickly for 100entries, correctly for 1000entries and very slowly for 10000. Impossible to use with 100k entries

Comment: Ah yes. That explains some things. So the problem size is increasing. In this case, I assume that the transaction is simply "too large" (i.e. too may rows are updated). I would suggest to process the entries in batch sizes. Your data suggests that a batch size between 100 and 1000 seems sensible.

Comment: Do you suggest to process like this : https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update I'll try to do this.

Comment: No. As the article says: "*Batching allows us to send a group of SQL statements to the database in a single network call. **This way, we can optimize the network and memory usage of our application.***" This will not resolve the problem with the transaction size. We need to iterate over the data, and make `n` calls to the `@Transactional` method, each modifyting `b` many entries (where `b` is the batch size). For this, we need to rewrite the `@Transactional` method such that we control which entires are processed wiith each call.